# Google Maps API - map not displaying - no errors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need your help please. I want to integrate a Google Map with javascript-api.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Google JavaScript API is enabled. My Domain is confirmed. In `key=YOUR_API_KEY`, i have entered my API-KEY.

The Google code example below of the "Simple Map" creates a blank page. 
No error message is displayed [console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS2xL.png)

It seems like the script is loaded, but the map will not be displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        
         <script>        
         var map;
         function initMap() {
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
         zoom: 8
          });
         }

        </script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

View this example page on my site [map.html](http://grossen.de/map.html)

Maybe someone can help me.

Thank You, Chris

Comment: There are errors. Look at the javascript console: `Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://grossen.de/map.html`.  Add that URL (or a wildcard URL that includes it) to the allowed referrers for your key.

Comment: Setting your map element to a % height might not be a good idea. Once you edited the referrers as explained in the answer(s), if you still don't see your map, try setting the map element height to a fixed height like `500px` instead of `100%`.

Comment: If you then need to know how you can have your map container height expressed as a relative height (%), search this website for answers (there are many) or ask another question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: oh, it works!  the div.#map ignore the styles in <head> If i add style attributes direktly to the div like `<div id="map" style="width:500px; height:200px;"></div>` I don´t know why, but it works!  - thanks

Comment: There is no reason for the map to "ignore" the styles in the head section. Anyway, as good practice you should do that in a separate CSS file but styles in the head should work too.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting "RefererNotAllowedMapError" error from Google script.
This means your URL was not successfully added to refferers list. Check if you added. At least on your example page. Try clearing cache or use Incognito window to make sure you are not getting any errors.

EDIT:
**Also make sure you set height to your map div! (it is set to 0 by default!)**

Comment: I'll second this, you need a width on the map in addition to the API permissions.

Comment: What about explaining clearly where OP has to do that? Link to the console, etc.?

Comment: Regarding your edit: it's true that you have to set a height, and OP did set a height but in %, which might trigger issues. You don't need to set a width and the default width is not 0.

Comment: @SeanKendle No. You don't. But you need a height.

Answer (score 2):

Log in to https://console.developers.google.com using your account that consist of google maps api then

- go to credentials
- click on your api_key entry from the list
- Under key restrictions either select none or add HTTP referrers as  *.grossen.de/*

Comment: I`ve added *.grossen.de/* bevore, and also i´ve tryed it without restrictions - both don´t work...

Comment: I can see that you have resized the map div. Call the following function inside initMap()

    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Answer (score 0):

First of all sorry for my maybe bad English.

I've had the same problem and found the following answers (In my case the first answer was the correct one):

- Billing has not been enabled on your account.
- The provided billing method is invalid (for example an expired credit
  card).
- A self-imposed daily limit has been exceeded.

Source: [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-key-and-billing-errors)

If you have the same answer, you can signup with a credit card here: [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial/signup/)

Comment: In the no-valid-payment-methods case, it may take as long as 10 days for the map to begin displaying after adding a bank account (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just need to give the height attribute and value (exactly value: like 200px) on the

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Like above @NeuTronas said, it solve my problem.

I also find out the official document instruction

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=zh-TW#if-your-code-isnt-working

Hope this can help you.